# Trying to install Java on a Rails Heroku app

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails app relies on legacy Java code for a piece of its logic. It runs the code via shell commands: `javac whatever` and then `java whatever`. However, after deploying to Heroku, the request fails because it can't locate `javac` or `java`.

What's the best way to install Java in a Rails app? I tried using a multi-buildpack solution, with this .buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git
```

But I get this error:

```
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

I tried forking the Ruby buildpack and installing Java directly from there, but I don't really know what I'm doing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `heroku-buildpack-jvm-common` instead of the Java buildpack. So your `.buildpacks` file will look like this:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

It's probably a good idea to put the JVM one before the Ruby one in case `javac` or `java` are needed at compile/build time.

The JVM buildpack is essentially the same as the Java buildpack, but doesn't install Maven and thus does not require a `pom.xml` file. The missing `pom.xml` is why you got that error I think.

**EDIT**

In the modern era, you can also run:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

Comment: I actually asked the Heroku people (and they responded almost immediately, which I was surprised about) - turns out that it only works if you put the Java one *first*. -_- No idea why. This is a great idea though (and confirmed it works). Thanks!

Comment: The order will only matter if you need Java during the compile/build phase for Ruby. In this case, since the Java part failed, I suspect it was the lack of a `pom.xml`.

Comment: Quite possible as well. 8-) I know that the Heroku people said that Java would need to be first.